# probem in recovering clash of clans in laptop

Tags: clash-of-clans

I played clash of clans in my laptop using blue stacks.

After some weeks blue stacks is unable to open it shows some error. Now I cannot play the game. I already connected the game to my Google+ account. Can I able to recover my village again after re installing blue stacks or is there any other way to get into my village.

Comment: Try to login again to your Google?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your account is linked with Google+ it is safe.

You will be able to access it on Bluestacks (or any mobile device) by entering this Google account again. Just make sure to click the Google+ button once you enter back in the game so that you get your village loaded.